# IndentationError: unexpected indent Python 3 Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, whitespace, indentation

with this following python 3 code :

`print("The nodes visited in the frontier are:", end = " ")`

i get this error

`IndentationError: unexpected indent`

how to fix this?

Comment: There must be some statement where you might have indented with white space and some with tabs. SO there is a error.

Comment: Add the full program here

Answer (score 0):

Correct

```
if 5 > 2:
    print("Five is greater than two!")
```

Incorrect

```
if 5 > 2:
print("Five is greater than two!")
```

Find more info here https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html
Or here (2.1.8. Indentation), https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#line-structure

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the space before print(). By your statement, I suppose this works well

```
print("The nodes visited in the frontier are:", end = " ")  #removed the space in the beginning
```

Comment: its still got an error